# Как вывести текст в определенном месте формы

Tags: c#, winforms, form, текст

Есть одна форма без textBox. Вопрос такой: можно ли при открытии формы отобразить в определенном месте необходимый текст, не используя textbox и label? И если да, то каким способом возможно это реализовать?

Comment: нельзя....текст должен быть отображен в компоненте

Comment: у меня просто по заданию затем при нажатии на любую кнопку (клавиатура) должно произойти дублирование этого текста в другой части экрана. даже не знаю, как это сделать: располагать textbox или label в нужных частях формы как-то не  эстетично)))

Comment: создайте label в коде. А вообще, если создать лейбл и не присвоить ему текст, то его видно не будет...

Comment: спасибо, разобрался как сделать)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо Виталию - разобрался как все реализовать)

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label label1 = new Label(); //создаем новый label1
        label1.Location = new Point(x, y); //прописываем расположение. например, (10, 10)
        label1.Text = "Привет"; //прописываем текст, который будет отображаться в label
        Controls.Add(label1); //показываем его при запуске
    }
```